# Como colocar os botões Run/Debug/etc. no lado esquerdo da barra?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Como posso deixar esse toolbar do Run/Debug/etc. na esquerda, como aparecem no Android Studio?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clique em **View -> Toolbar**. Pronto, os demais botões aparecerão e esses aí serão colocados do lado esquerdo.

Comment: putz q simples e eu me matando de graça sajdansjdasda